# What is the effect of phase transition on the thermodynamic state variables of a material?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, phase-transition

When a material undergoes a phase transition, it releases an amount of heat (under a specific temperature). So the effect of the phase transition on entropy would be equal to:

\begin{align}
\frac{L}{T_\text{transition}}
\end{align}.

Does a phase transition affect entropy in any other way? Since entropy is a function of state, my question boils down to how a phase transition affects the *state variables* of the material?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, enthropy is also a state variable of a material. When it comes to other state variables, if You assume the constant temperature of the phase transition, it should be followed by a constant pressure. Volume, internal energy, enthalpy and enthropy change. For example during evaporation of water all of them increase.

Answer (score 0):

Only first-order phase transitions involve latent heat (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition#Modern_classifications ). In general, thermodynamic variables can have singularities in phase transition points.